# What port does Visual Studio use to deploy an app to Windows 10 IoT

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, windowsiot

When a device is on a remote location (so not within the local network), how can I deploy an application to the Windows 10 IoT device from within Visual Studio? What ports need to be forwarded in the router. And second, (quiet important actually) how would the authentication work? When Windows Authentication is selected, does it use the current windows user? I would expect to be able to provide credentials that are set from within the web dashboard of Windows 10 IoT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port used to deploy an application by Visual Studio 2015 is 4020 [assigned by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592019.aspx). You can [set a different port number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441469.aspx#Configuring%20the%20remote%20debugger) of you like in Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor. Also, you can choose permissions to add or remove users that have permission for remote debugging.

For Windows IoT device you can select your device in [IoT Dashboard](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/downloads) and right click and select "Open in [Device Portal](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/deviceportal)". Then you can enter credential information.

In Debugging of Device Portal, you can start Visual Studio Remote Debugger if "msvsmon.exe" is not in Live process dumps list.

After that, you can deploy your app within Visual Studio using `"<your device ip address>:<port>"` as remote machine name. You can find "port" number after starting Visual Studio Remote Debugger like this:

[image]

You will be request to enter remote debugging PIN after deploying. This PIN you can edit in Home page of Device Portal like this:

[image]

More information about credentials processes in Windows Authentication you can reference [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn751047(v=ws.11).aspx).